# Camerabuttons events just not firing in WP7.1 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've diligently followed the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.camerabuttons.shutterkeyhalfpressed(v=vs.92).aspx to try and hook the camera events in my WP7.1 Silverlight app. In my main form I have:

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += new EventHandler(CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed);
    }
```

And then...

```
   void CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // stuff
    }
```

However, this event never fires. When I press the camera button, the phone just jumps to camera mode. Am I missing something? I got the sense from the above article that I might need to add the following to my WPAppManifest.xml, because the project was converted from WP7.0:

```
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
```

... but I did that, and nothing much changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the capture has not started (CaptureSource.Start), this event will not fire.

Comment: Oh! I can't use the camera buttons without running the camera? I was intending using them for screen shots!

Comment: you can actually. Just tested a half press and assigned it to showing a MessageBox and it worked. So you don't need to work with camera.