# Wp7 Camera Button Event

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

Within a Windows Phone 7 app, is it possible to capture the hardware camera button pressed event in code?
Right now when I press the camera button nothing happens and I can't figure out how to hook up to the event.

Comment: Same question as this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442571/camerabuttons-events-just-not-firing-in-wp7-1-app

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202963%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). This is an example of the events:

```
// The event is fired when the shutter button receives a half press.
CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += OnButtonHalfPress;

// The event is fired when the shutter button receives a full press.
CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += OnButtonFullPress;

// The event is fired when the shutter button is released.
CameraButtons.ShutterKeyReleased += OnButtonRelease;

// Provide auto-focus with a half button press using the hardware shutter button.
private void OnButtonHalfPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (cam != null)
        {
            // Focus when a capture is not in progress.
            try
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    txtDebug.Text = "Half Button Press: Auto Focus";
                });

                cam.Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception focusError)
            {
                // Cannot focus when a capture is in progress.
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    txtDebug.Text = focusError.Message;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```