# Detect lock button press

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, background-process

I have been asked to make a morse code app using Windows Phone 7.

I need to be able to press the lock button multiple times to trigger my app to detect what sequence and timings have been pressed.

For example if I press the lock button on my phone (HTC Radar) five times I want my app (which would be running in the background) to detect that it has been pressed five times and at what timings so that I could figure out .- or "short / long" patterns then open itself up.

How would I go about this?

I have used XNA and C# for XBOX but not for mobile devices.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't with the power button, but there's an API to use the shutter button of the camera. Not sure it'll pass marketplace certification though.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. What is the API for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973740/wp7-camera-button-event

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to solve your problem.

- Your application can subscribe to the Obscured event. But this event does not mean that  exactly lock button was pressed. It could be the SMS or phone call.
- You can't do the background application wich will run all the time, and handle lockscreen button.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. What is the closest I could get to a solution to this?

Comment: Just simple Silverlight application, with one button.